# Make Material-UI Reactjs FloatingActionButton float

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

After trying to find an example where the `FloatingActionButton` floats at its standard bottom-right screen position with no results, I come to you if you could provide one because it seems to be a normal button without floating to that corner by default.

Am I supposed to make it float by setting custom CSS rules?
Material-UI docs doesn't mention any property about floating [Material-UI FloatingActionButton documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/floating-action-button).

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) we can look at?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Indeed, no property for this in the component FloatingActionButton for the moment.

Waiting for it :

**1) A solution using inline styles :**

At the top of your component, add :

```
const style = {
    margin: 0,
    top: 'auto',
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 'auto',
    position: 'fixed',
};
```

... and in your render method :

```
render() {
    return <FloatingActionButton style={style}><ContentAdd /></FloatingActionButton>
}
```

OR

**2) A solution using CSS file**

Add in your CSS file (ex : styles.css referenced on your index.html) :

```
.fab {
    margin: 0px;
    top: auto;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: auto;
    position: fixed;
};
```

... and put on your React component :

```
render() {
    return <FloatingActionButton className="fab"><ContentAdd /></FloatingActionButton>
}
```

Comment: The much missing CSS nugget! Your contribution is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 24):

I actually found this on the [Material-UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#floating-action-buttons). I just made a few tweaks to it. Here's the resulting code.

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  fab: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: theme.spacing(2),
    right: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));
```

add this to your component

```js
const classes = useStyles();

return (
  <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add" className={classes.fab}>
    <AddIcon />
  </Fab>
);
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to manipulate CSS in material-ui, its better to use withStyles currying function.

Like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from "material-ui";
import {Add} from 'material-ui-icons';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
const style = theme => ({
  fab: {
    margin: 0,
    top: 'auto',
    left: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    right: 'auto',
    position: 'fixed',

  }
});
class MyPage extends Component{
render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
        return <Button fab variant="fab" color="primary" aria-label="add" className={classes.fab}><Add />
    </Button>
}
export default withStyles(style)(MyPage);
```

Documentation link: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/

Answer (score 13):

In MUI v5, you can add the one-off styles directly to the `Fab` component via the [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) props. Set the position to `fixed` (as opposed to `absolute` in other answers*) along with the anchor positions and you're done.

```
return (
  <Fab
    sx={{
      position: "fixed",
      bottom: (theme) => theme.spacing(2),
      right: (theme) => theme.spacing(2)
    }}
    color="primary"
  >
    <AddIcon />
  </Fab>
);
```

[image: Edit 35828991/make-material-ui-reactjs-floatingactionbutton-float]

*: Setting to `absolute` will anchor the button to the bottom right of the closest relative container, the container itself will be moved if the user scrolls down which in turn moves the button. Use `fixed` value to anchor the button in relative to the viewport, so the scrolling would not affect the button position.

Answer (score 5):

If you are creating a custom theme you can use the theme [overrides](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#css) to style the FAB (Floating Action Button) is floating in the bottom right corner:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";

export default createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiFab: {
            root: {
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: '2rem',
                right: '2rem'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This will override the FAB for every component usage. You can use the same style with a specific class name and override it again for other usages.

Comment: The position should be fixed instead of absolute in order for the fab to stay at it's position while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

In case of custom theme, in **MUI v5** the overriding of the style it's a bit different from the v4,
see [MUI v5-style-changes](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-style-changes/).

```
components: {
  MuiFab: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: '2rem',
        right: '2rem'
      }
    }
  }
}
```